# iron-ajax not support content-type='application/json' for POST request

Tags: json, polymer, polymer-2.x, iron-ajax

I am trying to use iron-ajax but the content-type='application/json' is not supporting.

```
<iron-ajax id="ajaxRequestOtp"
                               method="POST"
                               url="[[apiEndPoint]]/user-sms-auth"
                               body="{{requestOtpBody}}"
                               handle-as="json"
                               headers='{"Accept": "application/json"}'
                               on-response="_responseRequestOtp"
                               on-error="_errorResponseRequestOtp"
                               content-type='application/json'>
                    </iron-ajax>
```

Property -

```
static get properties() {
            return {
                apiEndPoint: {
                    type: String,
                    value: 'http://example.com'
                },
                requestOtpBody: {
                    type: String,
                    computed: '_createRequestOtpBody(mobileNumber)',
                    notify: true
                }
            };
        }
```

Computed function -

```
_createRequestOtpBody(mobileNumber) {
            let body = {
                phone_number: "+91" + mobileNumber
            }
            return JSON.stringify(body);
        }
```

This is not working, 404 Bad request. I need to send a JSON object to my server.

Error Message-

```
OPTIONS http://example.com/user-sms-auth 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 Failed to load http://example.com/user-sms-auth: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404
```

Comment: `iron-ajax` supports that `content-type` for `POST`, and indeed sends JSON data with the header set: [demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/rGxMMP?editors=1010). Do you have any details on the 400? Is there an error message that indicates the problem with the request? (e.g., is it a missing header? malformed body? etc.)

Comment: @tony19 - I just replace my **url** with the url u provided in the _codepen_ `//httpbin.org/post` and and kept all other things as same, and it started working. SO do you thing that the problem is in my backend server ???

Comment: It looks like you changed the received error code from "400 Bad Request" to "404 Bad Request", which isn't correct as **404** is the status code for "Not Found". If you're getting a **400**, that means something is wrong with your request. A **404** indicates you're requesting a resource that does not exist (i.e., bad URL).

Answer (score 0):

Make `requestOtpBody` => `type: Object`, and skip the `JSON.stringify` step.

```
_createRequestOtpBody(mobileNumber) {
    return { phone_number: "+91" + mobileNumber };
}
```

Comment: @rahul have you tried adding `with-credentials` to the `iron-ajax` element?